# Twitter login in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am developing a iPhone application in which user has to login through social networks ie Facebook,Twitter,GooglePlus.

The login functionality is just like this app : https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/fancy/id407324335?mt=8

I have logged in via facebook and its working fine. But I don't how to get the user details from the twitter and google plus.

Please provide me some sample source.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

To login to Twitter, the documentation provided here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios is pretty comprehensive.

There is a sample project with a few functionalities implemented in this project.

https://github.com/lucascorrea/SCTwitter

As for Google Plus, I don't think there is any better resource than this one.

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But i am not getting the twitter details

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to retrieve user details with the [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/) library:

```
STTwitterAPI *twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIAppOnlyWithConsumerKey:@"..." consumerSecret:@"..."];

[twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *bearerToken) {

    [twitter getUserInformationFor:@"twitterapi" successBlock:^(NSDictionary *user) {
        NSLog(@"%@", user);
    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        // ...
    }];

} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    // ...
}];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this i getting user data, and I am having one more query I am having twitter app in my iphone.It is possible to get the user detail from the twitter application

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. To get details about the user specified in iOS Settings, you should use the SLRequest class https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/making-api-requests-slrequest